# Is there an ambiguity in "the most purified gold"?

Tags: ambiguity

Is there an ambiguity in the question:

> Which country has the most purified gold?"

1. Which has (the most purified) gold? say 24 carat gold
2. Which country has the largest amount of purified gold in comparison to
   others?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Some may prefer to use a hyphen to disambiguate: "which country has the most-purified gold?" vs. "which country has the most purified-gold?", even though the hyphen is not strictly required.

Comment: Yes, I fell the same ambiguity as you do. In speaking, though, one could stress the meaning with the help of intonation.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity one can simply say 'Which country has the largest quantity of purified gold'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the expression sounds rather unnatural as it stands - perhaps because of the ambiguity, or perhaps because 'has' sounds a little colloquial for such a topic.

> Which country owns the largest amount of purified gold?

and

> In which country will one find the gold which has been most purified?

disambiguate, but the latter sounds clumsy. 'Which country produces the purest gold?' sounds better, though 'stockpiles' *may* just possibly be required.